# Is there something similar to singletonList in C#

Tags: c#

Java has `Collections.singletonList(T)` which returns a `List<T>` of exactly one element. Is there something similar in C# that returns an `IList`?

Comment: As per @eyelesscactus54, the easiest way to do this is: var mySingletonIlist = new[]{myVariable};

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question, no. Sadly there is nothing built in, although it would often be useful when working with IEnumerable. You'll have to roll your own.

**Update**

Instead of using workarounds, here's an example of an efficient and immutable SingletonList that implements `IList<T>`:

**Usage**

```
SingletonList<int> bling = new SingletonList<int>(10);
```

**Code**

```
public class SingletonList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private readonly T _item;

    public SingletonList(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return _item;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Add not supported.");
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Clear not supported.");
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        if (item == null) return _item == null;

        return item.Equals(_item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

        array[arrayIndex] = _item;
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Remove not supported.");
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return Contains(item) ? 0 : -1;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Insert not supported.");
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("RemoveAt not supported.");
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index == 0) return _item;

            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException("Set not supported."); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`IEnumerable<T> enumerable = Enumerable.Repeat(t, 1);`

Creates an IEnumerable with one element.

Answer (score 10):

`Array` implements `IList`; and the length cannot be modified via `Add` (as `ReadOnly` is `true`).

Thus, `SingletonList<int>` could be implemented as easily as:

```
var slist = new int[] { 5 };
```

You may want to wrap it in a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>` so that the single value cannot be changed (if the Java Singleton list works like this). E.g.

```
var slist = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new int[] { 5 });
```

You can also create an extension method.

```
public static IList<T> AsSingletonList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        return new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>(new T[] { item });
    }
    return new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>(new T[] { default(T) });
}
```

Or one that asserts there is exactly one value in the source:

```
public static IList<T> AsSingletonList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    IList<T> result = null;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (result != null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("source", "Source had more than one value.");
        result = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>(new T[] { item });
    }

    if (result == null)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("source", "Source had no values.");
    return result;
}
```

*Edit*: Used `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to prevent mutation of the single value.

*Note*: While I think the other answers are correct, the `List<T>` by default has a capacity of 10 - which is a tiny bit wasteful.

Comment: -1 This does not create an immutable single item list. You can cast the result back to an array, and then change the value.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static class IListExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> SingletonList<T>(this IList<T> iList, T item)
    {        
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(i => item).ToList().AsReadOnly();

        // or
        var Result = new List<T>();
        Result.Add(item);
        return Result.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `AsReadOnly()` and its even inmutable. So: `return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(i => item).ToList().AsReadOnly()`

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you can use a list initializer with one element:

```
var x = new List<int> { 3 };
```

Contrary to `singletonList`, this list is mutable. If you want something immutable, you can call `AsReadOnly()` on the resulting object:

```
// Looks strange, but, yes, this is actually valid C#.
var x = new List<int> { 3 }.AsReadOnly();
```

Answer (score 2):

I passed a `new[] { alreadyDeclaredVariable }` into the function. That's one way to do it, just making an in-place array of 1 element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the type of array can be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

This is a first for me: I am submitting an answer ... what I have to say does not lead itself to a comment, imho ... to a question which I think I do not fully understand ... in order to better understand the question. Consider:

```
    public class singletonList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public singletonList(T theValue) { base.Add(theValue); }

        public new void Add(T anotherValue) {}

        public new void AddRange(T anotherValue) {}

        public new void Clear() {}

        public new void Insert(int index, T anotherValue) {}

        public new void ToArray() {}
    }
```

This will create a new List of whatever Type which allows only one instance of its value-Type to exist inside the List. Obviously it's not fully 'fleshed-out' since you could still use 'InsertRange' and other List altering commands.

Here's a test verifying its 'immutable' for the internal List operators masked-out by the use of 'new' in their declarations.

```
    var q = new singletonList<int>(99);
    q.Add(100);
    q.Clear();
    q.Insert(0, 788);
```

I doubt this is what the OP wants, but I am curious if this perhaps does, meet the OP's spec in any way.

In spite of ChibaCity's kind explanations, I am still utterly baffled why one would ever want to use a List that contained only one element.

Thanks in advance for educating me, and if the cost of enlightenment is loss of votes, or face ... no problem; at my age I am not running for anything except staying in place, and face is best forgotten :)