# Store List in memory accessible to all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So I want to keep a list in memory, with a get and post method.

All users must be able to post and read from the **same** list. I've looked into

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

for a controller, but it only keeps the same list in memory for a single user.

So how can I implement a List which is accessible by all users?

My project is WebAPI, so it must be easily accesible by Rest.

Comment: Is there a reason you cant use a database?  That is the normal way to do things like this.

Comment: No, I want it to be stored in cache/memory. And the data stored in it will be changed very frequently. And the List should be rest every 12 hours.

Comment: You could do aome kind of [Singleton list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144833/is-there-something-similar-to-singletonlist-in-c-sharp) though you'll need to be very careful about mulitple people accessing the list similatneously

Comment: As Alex mentioned, you should be using database or some kind of storage for this. If you need this for some test purpose, may be maintaining a Static List might help - but be aware that the data in that list will be cleared when app domain reloads/recycles. Or may be you can use cache for this as well

Comment: Something like [Redis](https://redis.io/) would be a good option here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `HttpContext.Current.Application` instead which will be shared between all your users:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["someList"] = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
```

and then retrieve like this:

```
var myList = HttpContext.Current.Application["someList"] as List<string>;
```

As an alternative you could just use a static property:

```
public static class MyHelper
{
   static MyHelper()
   {
       MyList = new List<string>();
   }

    public static IList<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could use like this:

```
MyHelper.MyList = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
```

and to retrieve the value:

```
IList<string> myList = MyHelper.MyList;
```

This being said, be aware that if you are running in a web farm you might need to consider some distributed caching because `HttpContext.Current.Application` will be stored in-memory of the current web node.

Another important remark about this is that the `List<T>` class is not thread-safe so sharing a single instance between different threads could cause data corruption unless you properly synchronize the access to this list between the readers and writers by using the corresponding locking mechanisms or use `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead which is designed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a ConcurrentBag rather than a list, otherwise multiple people adding/ removing from the list will cause problems.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I will add a remark about thread safety in my answer.

Comment: So even I don't initialize the List, but call `IList<string> myList = MyHelper.MyList` it doesn't thow any null exceptions. Quite convenient.

Comment: So I won't have to initialize the list? I can just call MyHelper.MyList.Add("string"), and it will just work?

Comment: Yes, the list is already initialized in the static constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As Darin pointed out, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Application` to store values that must be available to all application instances on the server. You must be sure, though, to do any updates in a thread-safe manner so that multiple instances (i.e., request handlers) cannot update the same value simultaneously.

If you are running your application on a Web farm, so with multiple Web servers to handle more users, this is not a good option because `Application` state is local on each server. In that case it would be better to either store the shared state in a database or in a distributed cache such as Redis (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed).